# dynamically change language on flipclock.js

Tags: javascript, localization, flipclock

i'm trying to change the language of the labels on a FlipClock.js clock programatically, when the user selects a language from a dropdown.

i see how to set the language when instantiating the clock (https://github.com/objectivehtml/FlipClock/blob/master/examples/localization.html) and i see the docs here http://flipclockjs.com/api but I'm not sure how to dynamically change the language.

something like:

```
var clock = $('#flipclock').FlipClock(6000, {
    countdown: true,
    clockFace: 'DailyCounter'
});

clock.loadLanguage("es"); // change language? doesn't work
```

but that doesn't work. i also tried

```
clock.language = "es";
```

and that didn't work either. any ideas?

Comment: I can't seem to see anything on their API docs, so my suggestion may be a little convoluted. When the user chooses a new language, save the current time of the clock, destroy the current clock, and then reinstantiate it with the new language and old time

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var clock = $('#flipclock').FlipClock(6000, {
    countdown: true,
    clockFace: 'DailyCounter',
    language:'es-es',
});
```

Comment: Please explain your answer instead of only posting a code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

```
clock.setOptions('language', 'spanish');
```